# Add CSS with Jquery to dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

Someone can help me with the following.

I need to add style to dynamic HTML elements I add with Jquery, but I can not give it to them directly in a stylesheet, since the values of the attributes that I want to change, are different also depending on the element I add.

Simplifying things, I need to styles from Jquery to HTML elements that will add more later.

I appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding element dynamically, then at the time of element creation you can add the css on the element like.

```
$('<p id="createdParagraph"/>')
    .appendTo(document.body)
    .css("color": "white",
        "background-color": "#98bf21",
        "font-family": "Arial",
        "font-size": "20px",
        "padding": "5px");
```

or

```
$('p').append('<span class=your_class_name>)
```

If you want to use lot of properties in different cases then you can create all the possible classes in your stylesheet and you can add/remove those classes using jquery dynamically like -

```
$("p").addClass('class1');
$("p").removeClass('class1');
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest, unfortunately, this method does not help me because the CSS assigns it to the container where you are adding html, while I needed to give it to content that was adding however the code served me, although tube that change a bit the code you had to use it so as explicastes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery’s [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method to add new CSS properties to an item or change the values of existing properties dynamically using jQuery.

**HTML code:**

```
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

**JQuery code:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").css({
      "font-size": "20px",
      "text-align": "center",
      "padding": "40px"
    });
  });
```

You can see an example here: [How to add CSS properties to an element dynamically with jQuery](https://stackhowto.com/how-to-add-css-properties-to-an-element-dynamically-with-jquery/)